# Need help in writing queries using dynamoose

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

i am working on node js using dynamoDB with dynamoose. For example, let us assume we have a table Employees in which there is two attributes Branch and Domain. I have a given branch and domain, now i want to get all the employees under either the given branch or the give domain. Can anyone please give an example for above case?

Comment: What is the hash key and sort key of the table?

Answer (score 3):

Here is the code to query and scan.

The code connects to DynamoDB local instance.

**Employee Schema used:-**

> Branch - Hash Key
>
> No sort key in the table
>
> Domain - is the attribute

**Code:-**

```
var dynamoose = require('dynamoose');
dynamoose.AWS.config.update({
    accessKeyId : 'AKID',
    secretAccessKey : 'SECRET',
    region : 'us-east-1'
});
dynamoose.local();

var Schema = dynamoose.Schema;
var Table = dynamoose.Table;

var Employee = dynamoose.model('employee', { branch: String, domain: String });

Employee.get('UK').then(function (data) {
    console.log('Get :' + JSON.stringify(data));
});

Employee.query('branch').eq('UK').exec(function (err, data) {
  console.log('Query :' + JSON.stringify(data));
});


Employee.scan('domain').eq('Banking').exec(function (err, data) {
  console.log('Scan :' + JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

**Explanation:-**

- Employee.get(..) - Get the data by hash key
- Employee.query (..) - Get the data by hash key along with other attributes as needed
- Employee.scan (..) - Get the data based on non-key attributes